# Safari stretching flex item heights

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, flexbox, safari

I have a flex container, and in that container, I have a bunch of images.  Using flexwrap, and a flex-item width of 33%, this presents the images nicely ... in Chrome (that is, they maintain their aspect ratios).  In Safari, however, the images get stretched in the vertical direction which looks terrible.

Is there a fix for this?

(Note: For the code snippet below, you will have to open this post in both Chrome and Safari to see what I am talking about)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src='https://swipestack.s3.amazonaws.com/s/q/1.jpg' alt='1'>
            <img src='https://swipestack.s3.amazonaws.com/s/q/2.jpg' alt='2'>
            <img src='https://swipestack.s3.amazonaws.com/s/q/3.jpg' alt='3'>
            <img src='https://swipestack.s3.amazonaws.com/s/q/4.jpg' alt='4'>
            <img src='https://swipestack.s3.amazonaws.com/s/q/5.jpg' alt='5'>
            <img src='https://swipestack.s3.amazonaws.com/s/q/6.jpg' alt='6'>
            <img src='https://swipestack.s3.amazonaws.com/s/q/7.jpg' alt='7'>
            <img src='https://swipestack.s3.amazonaws.com/s/q/8.jpg' alt='8'>
        </div>
        
    </body>
    
    <style>
        .container{
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 400px;
            height: 550px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .container > * {
            width: 33.33333%;
        }

    </style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, which works only if you give the first and second images the same height of 475px as the others :

```
   <style>
    .container {
      width: 400px;
      height: 550px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: green;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .container:first-child {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
    .container > * {
      width: 33.33333%;
      height: auto;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't seem to work. With the proposed solution, you no longer get three items per row.  Also, the images each have their own height, instead of having the same height.

Comment: This is weird, it worked for me with both chrome and firefox...

Comment: I think it's Safari that's giving the problem.  I ended up switching from using flexbox to using css grid, and that seems to have solved my problem.